# Fórmula en Excel con parámetros de rutas de archivos

Tags: excel, formulas, microsoft-office

Tengo una hoja de cálculo de **Excel** (denominada Parámetros) donde asigno *3 parámetros*:

> A1 = Nombre archivo
>
> A2 = Pestaña
>
> B1 = C:\Carpeta[Nombre archivo.xlsx]
>
> B2 = Hoja 1 A3=Valor
>
> B3 = $A$10

Quiero crear una fórmula que concatene las tres celdas para obtener el valor de una celda de una hoja de otro archivo (los especificados en los parámetros anteriores) cuyo valor es 150.

Lo que hago es esta fórmula:

> ="'"&Parámetros!B1&Parámetros!B2&"'!"&Parámetros!B3

En lugar de devolverme el valor de esa celda, 150, lo que me devuelve es la concatenación de los valores especificados en la fórmula, es decir, me devuelve:

> 'C:\Carpeta[Nombre archivo.xlsx]Hoja 1'!$A$10

Si en la celda resultado selecciono la celda del archivo en cuestión, el resultado es correcto (150) y en la barra de fórmulas veo la siguiente fórmula:

> ='C:\Carpeta[Nombre archivo.xlsx]Hoja 1'!$A$10

¿Cómo hago para que devuelva el valor correcto y no la concatenación de los valores?
Muchas gracias.

Ampliando la pregunta, os paso una imágenes de como se ve en la hoja:
Estos son los datos o parámetros iniciales
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la hoja con la fórmula aplicada y el valor que muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, en la celda E4 aparece el valor correcto (creado a partir de la fórmula directa **='D:\Documentación\Clientes\Excel Traspaso[VARIABLES DIC.xlsx]Hoja 1'!$A$11)** y, en cambio, en la celda E5 la fórmula aplicada muestra la ruta pero no el valor.

¿Alguna otra sugerencia? Muchas gracias

Comment: Eso de parámetros que es?, creo que esta de mas... bueno revisa mi respuesta para ver si das con la solución, si tienes otra duda con gusto te respondo.  Saludos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función `INDIRECT` o `INDIRECTO`, anexo un ejemplo y referencias al respecto:

Lo que hace esta función es convertir TEXTO en referencias de **excel**, por ejemplo si tienes el texto `A1`, podrías poner la formula: `=INDIRECT('A1')` para obtener el valor de esa celda en especifico, que en este caso sería equivalente a `=A1`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te pongo otro ejemplo multiplicando valores obtenidos con al función `INDIRECT`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la imagen anterior si modificas el número de renglón veras como se actualizan los valores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Anexo el ejemplo de excel:**  [EjemploIndirect.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6czZhUzZHY09TRnc)

Por último te anexo la documentación de **Microsoft** al respecto:

> **INDIRECTO (función INDIRECTO)**
>
> *Se aplica a: Excel 2016 Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007 Excel 2016
>   para Mac Más... *
>
> En este artículo se describen la sintaxis de la
>   fórmula y el uso de la función INDIRECTO en Microsoft Excel.
>
> Descripción
>
> Devuelve la referencia especificada por una cadena de texto. Las
>   referencias se evalúan de inmediato para presentar su contenido. Use
>   INDIRECTO cuando desee cambiar la referencia a una celda en una
>   fórmula sin cambiar la propia fórmula.
>
> Sintaxis
>
> `INDIRECTO(ref; [a1])`
>
> La sintaxis de la función INDIRECTO tiene los siguientes argumentos:
>
> Ref    Obligatorio. Una referencia a una celda que contiene una
>   referencia de tipo A1 o F1C1, un nombre definido como referencia o una
>   referencia a una celda como cadena de texto. Si ref no es una
>   referencia de celda válida, `INDIRECTO` devuelve el valor de error
>   `#¡REF!`.
>
> Si ref hace referencia a otro libro (una referencia externa), el otro
>   libro debe estar abierto. Si el libro de origen no está abierto,
>   `INDIRECTO` devolverá el valor de error `#¡REF!`.
>
> Nota    Las referencias externas no son compatibles con Excel Web App.
>
> Si ref hace referencia a un rango de celdas fuera del límite de filas
>   de 1.048.576 o del límite de columnas de 16.384 (XFD), INDIRECTO
>   devolverá el error #¡REF!.
>
> Nota    Este comportamiento es diferente al de otras versiones de
>   Excel anteriores a Microsoft Office Excel 2007, que ignoran el límite
>   superado y devuelven un valor.
>
> A1    Opcional. Un valor lógico que especifica el tipo de referencia
>   que contiene la celda ref.
>
> Si a1 es VERDADERO o se omite, ref se interpreta como una referencia
>   estilo A1.
>
> Si a1 es FALSO o se omite, ref se interpreta como una referencia
>   estilo F1C1.

[Da clic para ver la función: INDIRECTO (función INDIRECTO)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/INDIRECTO-funci%C3%B3n-INDIRECTO-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

**Actualización(2017-01-11)**

Aplicaste la formula de una manera incorrecta, `INDIRECT` debe ir después del `=` y no como un `string` o cadena de caracteres.

Te voy a explicar mas a detalle con un ejemplo parecido a lo que quieres hacer.

[Descarga los archivos de ejemplo aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6dVhqODVZbzcwblU)

- Cree este archivo (en la ruta que tienes en la pregunta: D:\Documentación\Clientes\Excel Traspaso):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Después en el segundo archivo tomo los valores del archivo `VARIABLES DIC`, según las configuraciones correspondientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Se muestra que toma la información correspondiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto hago uso de la función `indirect` y también de la función `match` que busca un valor en un rango de valores.  Busco el `DNI` del archivo `Ejemplo.xlsx` en el rango `A1:A12` del archivo `VARIABLE DIC.xlsx`, la funcion `match` retorna el número de renglón dentro del rango, con este dato yo puedo armar bien el `string` de la formula y después usar `indirect` para traer el valor con la formula armada.  Se escucha mucho rollo, pero en realidad en sencillo y será necesario que descargues los archivos para ver las formulas funcionando.

Esta es la formula que utilizo para obtener en que renglón se encuentra un determinado DNI:

```
=MATCH(A11,INDIRECT("'"&$B$1 &$B$2&"'!"&$B$4),0)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener el valor de ese DNI utilizo la siguiente formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$B$1 &$B$2&"'!"&$B$6&E11)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último pondré los pasos para que se vea un poco mas claro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toda esta información la puedes probar y ver los archivos de ejemplo que añadí.

[Ejemplo.xlsx   y  VARIABLES DIC.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6dVhqODVZbzcwblU)

**Actualización 2017-01-17**

Abro el archivo `Ejemplo.xlsx` y es correcto lo que mencionas, se muestran las formulas como `#REF!`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me doy cuenta que tienes una opción de seguridad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y efectivamente no funciona si no esta abierto el otro archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se me ocurre es que pongas el link al otro archivo y le des clic solo para que se abra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tuve que modificar un poco, separar ruta y archivo, porque el nombre de archivo entre `"[]"` corchetes no funciona para el link, asi que lo deje sin corchetes y en las formulas del `INDIRECT` se los puse como `strings` concatenados.

Te anexo el archivo con el `link` para abrir el otro `workbook`:

[Ejemplo con link para abrir otro archivo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NrUmB-KIz6RVREQUtKaExlQWs/view?usp=sharing)

Al parecer lo que investigue es que no se puede sin tener abierto el otro archivo, lo que se me ocurre es poner el link como el ejemplo que anexe.  Saludos.

Comment: Hola Cristina, muchas gracias por tu amplia y detallada respuesta. No conocía esta función de Excel pero en mi caso no ha funcionado. Me sigue apareciendo la ruta en lugar del valor buscado. Voy a poner en mi pregunta inicial unas imágenes para que se vea bien como me muestra los valores.

Comment: Estas aplicando mal la formula, `indirect` no va como `string`... es una función directamente, debe ir después del `=`, te voy actualizar la respuesta y ponerte un ejemplo mas parecido a lo que tu estas haciendo

Comment: Excelente respuesta y muy completa. Te has tomado un gran trabajo, @CristinaCarrascoAngulo. Sabía de esta función, pero tus ejemplos la muestra mucho mejor que lo que yo tenía.

Comment: Gracias :-), me gusta explicar.  Saludos desde Sinaloa, Mexico

Comment: Hola Cristina. Perdona que no te haya contestado antes pero me ha sido imposible probar tu ejemplo antes. Primero de todo, impresionante tu explicación y ejemplo. Se entiende a la perfección. Segundo, ya he descubierto cual es mi problema (o el problema en sí): si no tengo abierto el archivo origen (VARIABLES DIC), la fórmula me da el error #¡REF!. Si abro este archivo, la fórmula devuelve el valor correcto. Con tu ejemplo me ha pasado lo mismo. ¿Es así como debe actuar la fórmula o solo me pasa a mi? Muchas gracias por tu esfuerzo.

Comment: Déjame hacer la prueba y actualizó la respuesta al respecto.  En mi caso si tenia abiertos ambos archivos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias otra vez Cristina por tu ejemplo y tus explicaciones, excelentes otra vez. Teniendo en cuenta que este inconveniente es así, haré lo que me sugieres para tener abierto el archivo origen y poder trabajar correctamente en el vinculado. Un saludo y felicidades por tu trabajo en este foro.

Comment: Según veo y debido a mi reputación, inferior a 15, no te puedo puntuar más alto pero por si es por mi, te doy un 10!!!. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti, cualquier duda me puedes contactar con mucho gusto cristina.carrasco.angulo@gmail.com