# Ruta de libro Excel en función de celda

Tags: excel

¿Cómo podría variar la ruta de búsqueda en función del valor de una celda?

Por ejemplo, con la siguiente ruta:

```
='C:\AAAAA_Numero\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1
```

Vincular "Numero" con el valor de una celda.

Para conseguir así las rutas:

```
='C:\AAAAA_1\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1  -> con celda A1

='C:\AAAAA_2\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1  -> con celda A2

='C:\AAAAA_3\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1  -> con celda A3

...
```

Si usamos la función `CONCATENAR()`:

```
B1 = CONCATENAR("'C:\AAAAA_";A1;"\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1")
```

siendo `A1 = 1`

nos devuelve en formato string

```
B1 = 'C:\AAAA_1\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1
```

Ahora, para convertirlo en una formula, podemos usar la función `INDIRECTO(ref)`:

```
C1 = INDIRECTO(B1)
```

Sin embargo, si ref hace referencia a otro libro (una referencia externa), el otro libro debe estar abierto. Si el libro de origen no está abierto, `INDIRECTO()` devolverá el valor de error `#¡REF!`.

¿Hay algún otro modo de hacerlo sin tener abiertos los libros externos?

Dejo un [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42363/f%C3%B3rmula-en-excel-con-par%C3%A1metros-de-rutas-de-archivos/42376#42376) donde se presenta el problema pero no se resuelve.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Usando la funcion concatenar: =CONCATENAR("CC:\AAAAA_";E61)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,

Si usamos,

B1 = CONCATENAR("'C:\AAAAA_";A1;"\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1")

siendo A1 = 1

nos devuelve en formato string

B1 = 'C:\AAAA_1\[Libro1.xls]Hoja1'!$A$1

Ahora, para convertirlo en una formula, podemos usar la función indirecto:

C1 = Indirecto(B1) 

Sin embargo, si ref hace referencia a otro libro (una referencia externa), el otro libro debe estar abierto. Si el libro de origen no está abierto, INDIRECTO devolverá el valor de error #¡REF!.

Comment: Por lo que está documentado, no parece que sea posible hacer lo que quieres sin usar macros. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect  Piensa que Excel es una hoja de cálculo, no una base de datos, que es como estás intentando utilizarlo en cierto modo.